# Javascript returning undefined on ice candidate

Tags: javascript, socket.io, webrtc

I am trying to implement webRTC and after adding a few Ice candidates I get this error: **Error: Failed to execute 'addIceCandidate' on 'RTCPeerConnection': The ICE candidate could not be added**

Also in the console undefined is being printed out.
Here is my code. Do you see anything wrong with my implementation of webrtc or what could be causing this error and the undefined being printed out in console? Thanks

```
console.log("The user connected to the socket");
socket.emit('readyToJoinRoom', {"signal_room": SIGNAL_ROOM});

//Send a first signaling message to anyone listening
//This normally would be on a button click

socket.emit('signal',{"type":"user_joined", "message":"Are you ready for a call?", "room":SIGNAL_ROOM});

socket.forward('signaling_message', $scope); 
$scope.$on('socket:signaling_message', function (ev, data) {
    displaySignalMessage("Signal received: " + data.type);
    // Setup the RTC Peer Connection object
    if (!rtcPeerConn) {
          startSignaling();
    }

    if(data.type != "user_joined") {
         console.log(data.message);
         var message = JSON.parse(data.message);
         console.log(message);
         if(message.sdp) {
             console.log("inside 2nd if statement");
             rtcPeerConn.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message.sdp), function () {

             // if we received an offer, we need to answer
             if(rtcPeerConn.remoteDescription.type === 'offer') {
                  console.log("inside third if for remoteDescription.");  // This never executes, error happens right before this line
                  rtcPeerConn.createAnswer(sendLocalDesc, logError);
             }
          }, logError);
  }
  else {
    console.log("addedddddddd ice candidate.");
    rtcPeerConn.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(message.candidate));
  }    
 }  
});

function logError(error) {
       displayMessage(error.name + ': ' + error.message);
}
```

Comment: for starters, which console message is showing undefined? are you sure you getting the ICE candidate string before attempting adding?

Comment: What is printed as the signal type before undefined? Where do you send the sdp and candidate messages?

Comment: rtcPeerConn.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message.sdp), function () this call triggers an error and I have a method that logs this error which I have display up above